# How to get SD card to import photos into one folder each time loaded

Tags: sdcard

How to fix photos loading in one picture at a time when you load an SD card? It used to ask you when up put in each SD card how to handle, now it doesn't. If I look at Settings/Devices/Autoplay - it's turned on and set to ask me everytime for removable card and Photos for memory card. Should that be ask me everytime too?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you reformulate it a bit maybe?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I think we can assume Windows, as no-one else has 'autoplay'. On Mac you can set the built-in Image Capture utility to do this type of task. You can even define behaviour per card or camera.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you're trying to do is transfer images from an SD card to your Windows computer... (your question is not exactly clear at this point)

> If I look at Settings/Devices/Autoplay - it's turned on and set to ask me every time for removable card and Photos for memory card. **Should that be ask me every time too?**

Yes.